# Create a regex that will accept a-z, A-Z, 0-9 but not .jpg, .JPG, .bmp, .BMP, .jpeg, .JPEG, .png, .PNG at the end

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex where it will accept a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and should not accept .jpg, .JPG, .bmp, .BMP, .jpeg, .JPEG, .png, .PNG at the end of the string. However these are allowed at the middle of the string. Except "." it should not also accept any special characters as well.

```
  Accept:
  -----------
  abc123
  Abc123
  abc png 123
  abc

  Reject
   ----------
  abc@!#$%^
  abc.png
  xyz.jpg
  abc.PNG
```

I have created the regex pattern like - [A-Za-z\u00C00-\u017F\- ] but not sure how I can move forward.

Basically here is what I need:

1 - Accept uppercase A-Z, lowercase a-z, numerical 0-9, hyphen, single quote, space, and dot

2 -  The following special characters with an accent are allowed:- á, â, ã, ê, õ (these are just a few examples)

3 -  The following characters are not allowed:- backward slash, forward slash, colon, asterisk, question mark, double quotes, less than, more than, pipe, and ampersand

4 - The following formats are not allowed:- URL links, images, and email addresses

Any help on this !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with lookahead:

```
/^(?!.+?\.(jpe?g|bmp|png)$)[a-z0-9 .'-]+$/i
```

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/mB7dD5

Comment: Thanks!! It's not accepting special character but if I'm putting abc.png it's accepting.

See this - http://jsfiddle.net/RxwF8/6/

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not working. If I'm putting hello, it's not accepting. See this - http://jsfiddle.net/RxwF8/7/.

Also I've modified my question a bit. Could you please look into the criteria.

Comment: That definitely works, you are making mistake of quoting regex. See this working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RxwF8/8/

Comment: Wow that works. @anubhava many thanks!! Can you please have a look at the four points I have mentioned in the Question. Can this be achieved. Anyway thanks for your quick support.

Comment: I have already included all the allowed characters as per point # 1. But it is not fair to change the nature of question like this after posting it differently earlier. I suggest you create a new question with all those points and close this question by accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negation `?!.` like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*.jpg)(?!.*.JPG)(?!.*.bmp)(?!.*.BMP)(?!.*.jpeg)(?!.*.JPEG)(?!.*.png)(?!.*.PNG)
```

**Edit:**
Also accept jpg, png, etc without dot. Now corrected by enclosing `.` with square bracket.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*[.]jpg)(?!.*[.]JPG)(?!.*[.]bmp)(?!.*[.]BMP)(?!.*[.]jpeg)(?!.*[.]JPEG)(?!.*[.]png)(?!.*[.]PNG)
```

Comment: Try without using `$` sign.

Comment: Yes It works. But if I put "abcpngabc" It does not accept. Also it's accepting special characters. Could you please look at the four points I have mentioned in the question? It does not work like that way.

Comment: It works but couple of points which I have mentioned in the question is not satisfying....

1 - The following special characters with an accent are allowed:- á, â, ã, ê, õ (these are just a few examples)

2 - The following characters are not allowed:- backward slash, forward slash, colon, asterisk, question mark, double quotes, less than, more than, pipe, and ampersand

Comment: Question seems too broad.  My suggestion is to include the layer that negate the characters.  Like add `(?!.*[*:\\/\?\"><|&])` to reject colon, asterisk, etc.  Again add the email pattern after `?!.` to reject email and so on

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If you have additional characters you wish to negate just add them to the first square brackets after the first carat.

```
 /[^|@!#$%^\/":*&<>?]{0,4}[^.][a-zA-Z]{3}?([a-zA-Z])$/
```

This is assuming you want to negate all ending extensions regardless if they are a real type or not.

This is the pattern I would use. If I wanted to include a period in the last four characters I would slice the last 3-4 characters off and see if they match an existing extension. If the last 3-4 characters are not an extension then allow the string.

In this case you could just use:

```
/[^|@!#$%^\/":*&<>?]*/
```

Then slice on the last 3-4 characters or split on a period to check extensions. You can also do substring to get the last few characters.